# Snowflake connection clientSessionKeepAlive

Tags: node.js, database-connection, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to working with snowflake, using the node.js driver found in the snowflake documentation https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html

I was initially creating a connection with the below configurations.

```
  account: process.env.SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT,
  username: process.env.SNOWFLAKE_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD,
})
```

However, the connection was dropping, so I added `clientSessionKeepAlive: true` to the connection config.

So my question is, does adding `connection.destroy()` after the query effectively disconnects from the server?

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a connection can be terminated by calling the connection.destroy() method. This immediately ends the session associated with the connection without waiting for running statements to complete.

See [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html#terminating-a-connection)

Comment: Hello @sergiu, thank you for your reply! I am facing another issue. Currently, I have called connection.destroy() after I execute a query. However, when I send another request, although in my execute query function, I call the snowflake.createConnection() again, I get the following error: Error [ClientError]: Connection already terminated. Cannot connect again. Any idea?

Comment: You need to provide example as I don't really know what you're doing there. There are 2 parts when establishing the connection, **createConnection** and **connect**. Are you using both?

Comment: @nahsiloh I was facing something very similar with parallel connections. I reproduced the issue in this repository https://github.com/victorhtc/snowflake-conn-error and reported to the snowflake team. They fixed it here https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-nodejs/commit/efd3b762266a826b599abd3eb125693fec287a61 which is still to be released.